# Cheap low specs board with network and audio

Tags: linux, audio, streaming

I'm looking for an IoT board with:

- wifi, bluetooth and ethernet
- audio input
- at least 64Mb of RAM
- at least 128Mb of flash memory

I'm trying to build an audio streamer box (for Sonos) which means a micro-controller probably won't be enough, so it needs to be able to run Linux.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can check the tables [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_single-board_computers) to see if something matches your requirements. I’d probably go for one of the Orange Pi’s.

Answer (score 2):

May be a bit biased here, since I've worked with this technology a fair amount and enjoyed it, but I'd go with a Raspberry Pi, personally probably the Raspberry Pi 3.

The board will cost ~$30, plus a microSD (unless you opt for a network boot which would save you that cost).

Audio input will be possible [through USB](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43320/raspberry-pi-3-audio-input).  Bluetooth, WiFi, and ethernet are all present.  Plenty of memory to run a Linux distro, such as Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is too long for a comment, and there is the beginning of an answer in it, especially if I get more info from the OP.

Can you define "cheap"? Sub $5? $10? $120? $50?

And, what does "Arduino input" mean?  Pin comparability? Code comparability? sing he Arduino IDE?

For instance, ESP32 comes with BT & WiFI out of the box, and is certainly cheap, even with that memory. Some (a few, not the majority) have Arduino pin compatibility, so can take an Arduino shield - which would allow you to add Ethernet.

Raspberry Pi Zero W is cheap enough, if you need Linux, as is Orange Pi. Both have Arduino shield compatible HATs, allowing them to use any Arduino shield. They can also be made to run Arduino sketches (code).

E.g [Raspberry Pi to Arduino Shields Connection Bridge](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/raspberry-pi-to-arduino-shields-connection-bridge)